# Windows CE project can't add *.dll for SQL Server CE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I am developing a software for windows ce devices, using SQL Server CE. I want to add a reference to `sqlceme35.dll`, because it gets me the following message when debugging:

> Can't find PInvoke DLL 'sqlceme35.dll'.

If I try to add a reference to this dll, I get the message:

> A reference to sqlceme25.dll couldn't be added'.

I have the *.dll's from the installation directory

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5
```

The device I'm running the application with runs on Windows CE 6.0.

What am I missing?

Edit: After solving this problem, I got a new one: I have a reference to system.data (v.3.5.0.0, path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Data.dll`)

But I get the message

> The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

But to me, it doesn't seem to make sense that a newer version is not supported... Or am I misunderstanding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Device SDK and use those files. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8831

(Or even better use the .cab files)

Comment: Thank you. But I still get the message "Reference couldn't be added'.

Comment: What file (version and path) do you reference?

Comment: I solved it! If anyone has the same problem: Instead of adding the above named file, add a reference to `System.Data.Sqlserverce.dll` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop`

Comment: Solved the second problem: instead of desktop-directory, use device-directory for sqlserverce.dll